How's this puzzle? So far, fine
Preface
Here's a connections wall with some of my personal favourite things in it.
Partial answers are more than welcome. This one requires some knowledge and it may help you all to cooperate.
Wall











CHIP
PALACE
TEDDY
FAT


DRUM
MILK
DIM
MONICA


TREACLE
UNI
TECHNIQUE
ELDRITCH


DAVID
BEETHOVEN
HENRY
PERKY



Clues
Category Clue

 Aren't you glad to see me? I'm not promising eternal life, but you'll get bragging rights. Hopefully, some kindred spirit will know what to do here.  All this puzzling can't be good for you, though.

Theme Clue

 There's a small hint hiding in the title of this question, that will nudge you closer to the more specific theme.


Is this really a [tag:connections-puzzle]? It looks more like a [tag:connect-wall]

Instead of that hint should the literature tag be more suitable

Tag added :) Thanks!

These 'favourite things' of yours are all...

 ...works of Science Fiction & Fantasy. This is clued in the title's use of 'So Far Fine', in which lurks 'SFF', the abbreviation for the genre.

The wall resolves as follows (in solving order):

 Group 1: Characters in the short story 'Supertoys Last All Summer Long' (Brian Aldiss, 1969), the basis for Spielberg's 2001 movie A.I. Artificial Intelligence
 DAVID, HENRY, MONICA, TEDDY.

Group 2: Elements of the plot in A Clockwork Orange (Anthony Burgess, 1962)
 BEETHOVEN (Alex's favourite composer),
 DIM (a member of Alex's gang),
 MILK (the drink of choice at Alex's hangout, the Korova Milk Bar),
 TECHNIQUE (the Ludovico Technique - the behaviour modification treatment inflicted upon Alex).

Group 3: Philip K. Dick character names
 Joe CHIP (from Ubik, 1969),
 Palmer ELDRITCH & PERKY Pat (both from The Three Stigmata of Palmer Eldritch, 1964),
 Horselover FAT (Valis, 1981 - and others...).

Group 4: Words from names of locations in Terry Pratchett's Discworld series
The Mended DRUM (a tavern),
The Patrician's PALACE (the ruler's residence),
TREACLE Mine Road (one of the main thoroughfares in Morpork),
The Unseen UNIversity (a school for wizards).


We have a winner! Very well done, was worried nobody would crack it!
